# Tricky Separable Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please guide me:

$y' + ay +b = 0$ ($a$ not zero) is supposed to be separable and has solution

$y = ce^{-ax} - \frac ba$

Here is my start to this problem:

$\frac{dy}{dx} + ay = -b$ is as far as I can go with this. How should I go about separating $x$ and

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} +ay+b = 0$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -ay-b$

$\dfrac{dy}{ay+b} = -dx$

Now, can you solve this?

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense and yes I can solve this. The integral on left is a natural logarithm. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

We can take the differential equation $$y' + ay +b = 0$$ and write $$y'+ay = -b$$ then multiply by $e^{ax}$: $$e^{ax}y'+ae^{ax}y = -5 e^{ax}$$

Now the term on the left becomes $$(ye^{ax})' = -5 e^{ax}.$$ Next antidifferentiate and solve for $y$.

Comment: I like this alternative way to solve this.

Comment: Thank you :) It is a favorite approach of mine.

Answer (score 2):

You want to rewrite the equation in the form $f(y)dy=g(x)dx$. There is no need to isolate the constant, as it can be considered a function of $y$ (a constant function). Hint: $g(x)=1$

Comment: Of course now I see it. Thank you for your help.